# R Pipe Function not returning anything

Tags: r

I tested the line of code I wanted to run in cygwin (since I am using window), which is as follow:

```
/cygdrive/f/Data/testFolder
$ awk -F "," '{if($3 == 10948514) {print}}' < testfile.csv | head -n 20
20180301050630663,3122,10948514,abcd,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630663,3212,10948514,abcd,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630663,3122,10948514,abcd,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630663,3212,10948514,abcd,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630663,312,10948514,abcd,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630663,3212,10948514,abcd,,,,,,,,,,
```

And it seems to work fine on Cygwin.

However, since I am using R for data analysis and I intend to use the `pipe` function within R to filter out the lines of the Huge dataset to be read into R.

I have the following line of code within the `read.csv` function (note that the csv does not have any headers at all):

```
pipe(paste0("awk -F \",\" '{if($3 ==" ,10948514,") {print}}' < testfile.csv",sep=""))
```

which only returns

```
A connection with                                                                                                                   
description "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c awk -F \",\" '{if($3 ==10948514) {print}}' < testfile.csv"
class       "pipe"                                                                                                 
mode        "r"                                                                                                    
text        "text"                                                                                                 
opened      "closed"                                                                                               
can read    "yes"                                                                                                  
can write   "yes"
```

**Problem:** nothing is being read at all. The `pipe` returns nothing but the things above. I am wondering what actually went wrong. Could it be because the cmd do not recognise the `awk` command. If yes, then do invoke cygwin within the `pipe` function ? Could it be something else ?

I am very confused now.

Can someone give me a solution to solve this issue please ? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you prefer to use system() and put your unix command there. I use it and it works pretty well.

Comment: So the documentation for `pipe` (along with all the other related functions documented there) states that it returns a **connection object**. i.e. these functions return a connection object that is then used for passing data back and forth by something else. I agree that you may simply be mistaking this for the functionality of `system()`.

Comment: So would I be able to use `system(awk ...)` to output rows and at the same time read them into the csv ? Is this possible ?

Comment: It would probably make more sense to use `system()` to call `awk` in a way that dumps the results into another delimited file, and then use more standard tools to read that delimited file into R. Even cleaner, frankly, would be to put the data in a SQLite db and simply query what you want from R.

Comment: Problem is I have to loop through multiple huge datasets. I guess I will try to work with `sqldf` package then

Comment: I don't see why multiple large data sets would pose a problem for using SQLite. And `dbplyr` and `dplyr` with SQLite is another very good option.

Comment: Sorry. Is SQLite a package ? Because I will be downloading the 60 huge data files on a monthly basis and then have to preprocess the data. That's why I am thinking about running a script to preprocess the data right after I download the huge csv file from the internet every month.